# How to apply SetFilterRange function conditionally when there are different types of data in SphinxSearch?

Tags: php, sphinx

I am using Sphinx 2.1.4-id64-release for one of my php works for managing events and venues. I have created an index for storing details whenever an event or a venue is created or updated. I have start and end date timestamps for events stored in them. For venues, I am  keeping these values as zero. There is also a 'type' field for distinguishing events and venues. Type value 1 for events and 2 for venues.

I have 3 search criteria's on the front end, namely: All, events, venues. So, if I type in the keyword and click 'All', search result will contain both events and venues, if any.

```
$cl = new SphinxClient();
$cl->SphinxClient();
$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$cl->SetRankingMode(SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25);
```

For event criteria,

```
$->setFilter('type',array(1)); // type 1 for events
$currentTimestamp    =   time();
$cl->SetFilterRange('endtimestamp', (int)$currentTimestamp, (int)2000000000);// for events that are not expired.
```

For venue criteria,

```
$cl->setFilter('type',array(2)); // type 2 for venues
```

My problem is with the 'All' criteria.

```
$cl->setFilter('type',array(1,2)); //for both events and venues.
```

Here, if I apply the same 'SetFilterRange' condition, it will not include the venues as the timestamp fields are stored as zero for them.

How can I achieve search that includes only non expired events and venues ? Is it possible to achieve this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this will do.

```
$currentTimestamp    =   time();
$cl->SetSelect("*, IF(endtimestamp >= $currentTimestamp, 10, 0) + IF(endtimestamp <= 0, 10, 0) AS datefilter");
$cl->SetFilter('datefilter', array(10,20));
```

This seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Just give venues an actual end time. eg, if you where to set endtimestamp to 2000000000 for all venues, then

```
$cl->SetFilterRange('endtimestamp', (int)$currentTimestamp, (int)2000000000);
```

would find the venues too.

- In fact, it could be used to advantage, if an venue closed, could set the appritate timestamp, then it wouldn't appear in search results after it closed. (you could instead delete the record, but keeping the record there to link up with historic events could still be useful)